# How can I Immediately mask password characters with dots using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to eliminate the delay when entering a password in Xamarin.Forms. I haven't found any solutions on the internet.

```xml
<local:NoDelayEntry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Password" />
```

```cs
class NoDelayEntry : Entry
{
    public NoDelayEntry() : base()
    {
        this.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Customize the behavior as needed
        this.IsPassword = true;

        this.Text = new string('●', e.NewTextValue.Length);
    }
}
```

I have attempted the following so far; however, when I log in, the original password text is replaced by '●'. Is there a way to retain the original password while still using the masking behavior?

Comment: There's a very specific reason that the default controls show the letter for a short duration, it's very hard for people typing on a mobile device to be sure they have used the correct letter. So I would strongly advise against doing this.

Comment: Could you further explain your problem - what you are describing sounds like the intended behaviour

Comment: I understand the rationale behind the default controls showing the letter briefly for mobile users. However, I am aware of this and  would like to change the default behavior for my specific needs. Thank you @DavidG

Comment: The default behavior is an obnoxious malfeature that can be turned off under Privacy in Android settings. If this is a bottom-up (user) requirement rather than a top-down (management) requirement, maybe you can just instruct users how to turn it off. Though I'm not sure if the system setting will affect Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
   
        <StackLayout  Padding="20">
            <Entry x:Name="entry" TextChanged="entry_TextChanged" WidthRequest="200"/>
            <Button Text="view_password" Clicked="Button_Clicked" WidthRequest="200"/>
            <Label x:Name="label" TextColor="Red"/>
        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private static string Password = "";
    bool i = false;
    
    public MainPage () { InitializeComponent (); }

    private void entry_TextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        entry.IsPassword = true;
        if (i = !i)
            {
                if (e.NewTextValue.Length > Password.Length)
                    {
                        Password = Password + e.NewTextValue?.Last ();
                        entry.Text = new string ('●', e.NewTextValue.Length);
                    }
            }
        if (e.NewTextValue.Length < Password.Length)
            {
                Password = Password.Remove (Password.Length - 1);
                entry.Text = new string ('●', e.NewTextValue.Length);
            }

        label.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = Password;
    }
    
}
```

Here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/xgsCmoV).